# How to convert this structure to flex-box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The current design based on tables looks like this (the pictures are of the different size and ratio; the goal is to make all the imgs and text fit on same line and resize pictures preserving the ratio):

```
<style>
    table td, table td *
    {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    img
    {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="Pics/m51_1.jpg" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="Pics/hubble.jpg" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my straightforward attempt to convert it to flex-box design is the following:

```
<style>
    div
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    img
    {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div>
        <img src="Pics/m51_1.jpg" />
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="Pics/hubble.jpg" />
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly in all the major browsers (different bugs in Chrome, FF and Edge). Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.img, .text{
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text           
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text           
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does flex: 1 1 0px; do exactly ?

Comment: to make columns equal if contents of the items make it grow bigger

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close from what you needs, hope it help.

```html
<style>
    div
    {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content:
    }
    .image-container{
      width:30%;
      height:100%;
      position:relative;
    }
    .image-container img
    {
        width: 100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
</style>
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="width:50%">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-signlabel-features-speech-bubble-260nw-1223219848.jpg" />
    </div>
        <p style="width:70%">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%">
        <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/example-signlabel-features-speech-bubble-260nw-1223219848.jpg" />
    </div>
<p style="width:70%">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

basically what you need to do is make sure 2 image and 2 text per row, so that means each box is 25% width, then you need to make the flexbox wrap its content, and make it aligned to top

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item{
  flex: 1 25%;
}

.flex-item.text{
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-item img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item text">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/687px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item text">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/687px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item text">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item text">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div></section>
```